# Error Secure VPN Connection terminated locally by the Client. Error 412

Tags: cisco, vpn

Error Secure VPN Connection terminated locally by the Client. Reason 412: The remote peer is no longer responding.

i get this error while attempting connection to cisco vpn client program.

Comment: Some more information could be useful. See also http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/292/network-engineering-question-checklist

Comment: ok. thank you. i'll make myself more clear next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong password.  Also you can try tweaking the connection settings (port number, etc.).  Otherwise, contact your network administrator.

Comment: Yeah i tried connection settings and added port numbers as exceptions on firewall but still had the problem. But i would like to know how a network administrator would fix this.

Comment: Net admin would add the group name/policy.

Comment: Thank you! I would like to become an administrator so thats why im curious and as well i like everything about networks.